# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized in .NET Remoting

Tags: .net, authentication, exception, remoting, http-status-code-401

I developed a remoting service (hosting .NET type in the ISS).
IIS is configured to use "Integrated Windows Auth".

It works perfectly when I execute unit test the service on the "localhost"
(the code below is the code I use for testing), but after I have deployed a service to the test server (which in another another domain),
it started throwing a "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." exception.

```
string url = string.Concat(@"http://", serverName, "/", ServiceName);

IDictionary props = new Hashtable();
props["useDefaultCredentials"] = true;
props["useAuthenticatedConnectionSharing"] = true;

BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider srv = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider clnt = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
this.channel = new HttpChannel(props, clnt, srv);

ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(this.channel, false);

IMyService service = Activator.GetObject(typeof(IMyService), url) as IMyService;

service.GetData();// this error returns "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." exception.
```

What might be the issue? Is it domain related? May be it has something to do with a configuration of the default web proxy?

Answer (score 0):

What credentials are you using? Is the system using Windows authentication? If so, does the other domain accept users from your domain?

You may have to define a trust relationship between domains, or log in with different and appropriate credentials for the server's domain.